# Issue with rendering screens & background in python arcade

Tags: python-3.x, arcade

I am having difficulty getting a simple python Arcade app to work on my Win10 machine. I think the issue is with the "start_render" function not taking effect. I have the following issues:

- the screen does not "redraw", i.e., all existing sprites remain on the screen and are never removed. if I run some of the builtin code samples I get the character redrawn on the screen 100s of times as it moves
- the background color is never drawn on; it always remains black
- Using the "finish_render()" method in the on_draw() method does not work either; it creates a constant flickering and not a stable view

The sipmle code I'm running is below.

```
import arcade

class TestUI(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__( width, height, title)

    def setup(self):
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.csscolor.BLUE)


    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_circle_filled(100,100,50,arcade.csscolor.TEAL)

def main():
    app = TestUI(1200,800,"Test game")
    app.setup()
    arcade.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gives me a Teal circle on a full black background. If I run one of the code examples

```
python -m arcade.examples.sprite_moving_platforms
```

I get the constant redrawing (see screenshot)[image]

I am running the following versions:

- Python 3.7.4
- Arcade 2.5.7

On a Windows 10 machine

Any pointers on what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not reproducing to me. Try to update to latest Python/Arcade versions.

Comment: This is the latest arcade version if I'm not mistaken. Will try updating Python itself. Right now I'm using a workaround to just draw a filled square on every call of draw_update()...

Answer (score 1):

In function `on_draw` you need add at first `self.clear()`